# How to disable autoescape when using django template from_string() and render()?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-postoffice

I am sending an email using [django-post_office](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office), which renders the subject line using django templates:

```
subject = engine.from_string(self.template.html_content).render(self.context)
```

Django templates automatically [sets autoescape=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) for security, which means if you have an HTML character such as `Here's an email` it will produce a string with the character escaped: `Here&#x27;s an email`.

How can I disable autoescape when using `from_string` and `render` in this way to display the email subject appropriately?

An alternative example:

```
from django.template import engines
template = engines['django'].from_string("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
context = {"my_name": "<FooBar's>"}
print(template.render(context))
```

Results in:

```
My name is &lt;FooBar&#x27;s&gt;.
```

Comment: can you just change the engine option of autoescape to false?

Comment: @ha-neul that would work, but how do you do that for just this one variable?

Comment: in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/, search ```engine```, it says: ```DjangoTemplates engines accept the following OPTIONS:``` You change it to ```False``` in ```'OPTIONS'```

Comment: Yes, but that would require an entire reset of the templating engine, which is a security risk. How do I do it in this one context?

Comment: just a thought: maybe define a ```custom_from_string``` function may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, could you show how that would work? I don't know how you would subclass an engine like that.

Comment: it seems overkill. iklinac's answer with {{my_name|safe}} sounds like a way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just want to escape you string using proper [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) template tags

```py
{% autoescape off %}
{{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

or just mark it as [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe)

```py
"My name is {{ my_name|safe }}.
```

You can also escape by setting [`engine.autoescape`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e13954d2cfe8fba2045076b20a863aa7614937e6/django/template/engine.py#L31) to False

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could apply `.from_string("{% autoescape off %}My name is {{ my_name }}.{% endautoescape %}")` but it doesn't feel very pythonic. Is there a way I can pass the flag to the constructor for this one template without changing the flag for the entire engine?

Comment: why don't you just mark variable as safe, explicit is better than implicit